# Templated function name lookup conundrum(ADL)

Tags: c++, templates, mismatch, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

Given the following bit of code, why is it that the Generic function is invoked instead of the more specific SomeClass based function?

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass
{
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T)
{
   std::cout << "foo() Generic - Undesired function\n";
}

template <typename T>
void foo(const SomeClass<T>*)
{
   std::cout << "foo() SomeClass<T> - Desired function\n";
}


int main()
{
   SomeClass<char>* sc = new SomeClass<char>();
   foo(sc);
   return 0;
}
```

Note: If I were to remove the const from the "`void foo(const SomeClass<T>*)`" definition, the desired function is invoked. I've also tried rearranging the foo's though it had no affect. If possible can some please invoke the relevant areas in the standard that describe this particular ADL scenario.

With const: http://ideone.com/DIchLl

Without const:  http://ideone.com/Iam4LV

With const (1st):  http://ideone.com/W6PoJw

Comment: There is nothing specific to ADL here:  if the call is qualified, `foo(T)` is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Because the one without `const` requires less conversions. When the compiler is selecting an overload, it first looks for ones that match exactly, then it goes through a series of conversions in a specific order, and the first one found is the one used.

In this example, `sc` is a `SomeClass<char>*&`. The compiler first tries an exact match, and since there is none, it tries removing the `&`. Since it finds one then, it quits looking, and doesn't add the `const` which would allow it to see the other.

Comment: +1, just one quick question, If attempting to add a "const" is the secondary measure, why is it still matching the generic function in the following edit: http://ideone.com/KVsVI8   Is it because the T is still a better match?

Comment: In `const T`, the `const` is a top-level qualifier and does not affect the type of the function or overload resolution.  (A function declared as `void f(int)` is the same as a function declared as `void f(const int)`; top-level qualifiers only affect the _definition_ of the function, where they prevent modification of the argument.)  The `const` applies to the whole `SomeClass<char>*`, so it yields `SomeClass<char>* const`, not `const SomeClass<char>*`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Does the parameter being a pointer somehow make a difference?

Comment: No, in `const T`, `const` always applies to the whole `T`, not just to some part of `T`.  If `T` is `int*`, then `const T` is `int* const`:  the `const` applies to the whole `int*`, it can't reach inside and apply just to the `int` part of the `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

`foo(T)` is an exact match for the argument with `T` = `SomeClass<T>*`.

`foo(const SomeClass<T>*)` requires a qualification conversion (to add the `const` qualifier).

An exact match is better than a match that requires any sort of conversion, even if it is just a qualification conversion.

Comment: If I do the following it seems to work: http://ideone.com/F1woR3   So it seems to suggest that pointers are in play when doing lookup.